# Why are justify-content and align-items being ignored?

Tags: html, css

In the snippet below, why are `justify-content` and `align-items` having no effect?  I would expect the column to be centered within the containing box, with the extra space at the bottom distributed around the boxes.  Why is this not the case?

[image]

```css
.column {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
}
.card {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: firstly you are only showing some code. secondly are you using flexbox or just taking code from another site?

Comment: wrong.  firstly i have included a runnable snippet with all my code.  second, i wrote this code, it is not from another site.

Comment: Then are you using flexbox? if you arnt then this will not work (also including a snippet with out the includes of flexbox wont work)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `display: flex;` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo, as that's the basic reason for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

```css
.column {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
}
.card {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No.  They should be displayed as `flex column`, not `flex`.

Comment: That doesn't exist. Do you mean `flex-direction: column`?

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I had it in my head that it was a shortcut, and didn't realize they were only displaying downward because the flex was being ignored due to an invalid value.

Comment: @Jonah - One useful shorthand property [is `flex-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow) which incorporates `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap`.

Comment: @misterManSam, yes, i think that's where my confusion originated.  i was remember a multi-valued property with "column", and assumed it was `flex` itself

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have given is correct. But you should not give the flex direction in the display itself.

display:flex;
-webkit-flex-direction:column;

html:

```
<div class="column">
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Css:

```
<style>

.column 
{
border: 2px solid black;
display:flex;
-webkit-flex-direction:column;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items:center;
height: 300px;
width:500px;
}
.card {
background: red;
border: 1px solid green;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}

</style>
```